# What are the true cons of Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, frontend

I know that Redux is a just option.
While thinking about whether to use Redux or not, I was looking for articles about cons and pros, but there were few recent articles. Old articles have content that I couldn't agree with.

The articles say that boilerplate code and performance are cons of Redux. but, Is it true even now?

##### Encapsulation

In redux structure, I could access any data(No encapsulation). but, I didn't. It depends on the developer's capabilities and I can care about encapsulation as much as I want.

##### Cohesion

When I used redux, My code had more cohesion. Data mutation logic is placed in the slice for every feature.

##### Boilerplate code

I indeed have to make code as the redux way in the Redux structure.
I had to write a little more code in Redux structure, but it was a little bit. Rather, more parts can be reused when using Redux.
When we make a controller in the back-end, we make code in a framework-dependent way. There is almost no one who makes the controller from very low levels because of the flexible design.

##### Performance

I have made views for some complex use-cases using react-redux. but, I could find meaningful performance down. I think it is also meaningless that there is a performance down due to hundreds of KB of Redux packages.

##### So my question is...

- The articles about Redux cons I read were written 2 years ago. Using the Redux toolkit is a standard way now. Boilerplate code still is a con of Redux?
- If the performance down is a con of Redux, Could you tell me specific examples? (What kind of project has performance problems when using redux, or the cases that don't use Redux because of performance.)
- What is the biggest con of using Redux today? (Except that it's hard)

Any other thoughts or opinions, please let me know.

Comment: It’s hard to answer this question properly, since it’s gonna be opinionated in some way. Personally I view redux as a very simple lib that can’t go too wrong itself. Read the source code, it’s concise and does its job well. Things go wrong when you dive into the so-called “ecosystem”, so many conceptually over complicated solutions that seem tempting, but when used blindly will screw you up.

Comment: Different patterns and architectures don't have _pros and cons_ **in isolation**, they only have pros-and-cons in comparison to some other architecture or pattern. So far you've only written about Redux - you need to compare it to something first.

Comment: "I know that Redux is a just option" - what do you mean by "a just option"?

Comment: "The articles say that boilerplate code and performance are cons of Redux" - **what articles** are you referring to? Accusations of needing boilerplate code is not a criticism of Redux I'm familiar with. On the contrary, Redux _reduces boilerplate_ compared to the older Flux pattern: https://redux.js.org/usage/reducing-boilerplate

Comment: Modern Redux has *very* little boilerplate since it does not use switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPES or connect any more. Unfortunately many outdated articles still reference that outdated style of Redux, which is about 4 times as much code. To get a grasp of modern Redux, best follow the official tutorial at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Comment: Also, Redux does not come at "hundreds of kilobytes". The Redux core is 1.5kb and when you use Redux Toolkit and React-Redux, you will arrive at around 15kb, or 25kb if you really use all the features including RTK Query

Comment: @phry How'd you get Redux down to 1.5KB? That's barely larger than the `module.exports` in the package `index.js`. The smallest I can get `redux.min.js` is 6KB but you do really need `redux-toolkit` (33KB) otherwise you'll end up reinventing the wheel... poorly.

Comment: @Dai the `@reduxjs/toolkit` (including immer and Redux) is 11kb gzipped (this will usually be transferred): https://bundlephobia.com/package/@reduxjs/toolkit@1.7.0
Then you add 4-5kb for react-redux. Depending on what you use and how your bundler tree-shakes it will be less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While thinking about whether to use Redux or not, I was looking for articles about cons and pros, but there were few recent articles

Different patterns and architectures don't have pros and cons in isolation, they only have pros-and-cons in comparison to some other architecture or pattern. So far you've only written about Redux - you need to compare it to something first.

> The articles say that boilerplate code and performance are cons of Redux. but, Is it true even now?

Accusations of needing boilerplate code is not a criticism of Redux I'm familiar with. On the contrary, [Redux actually reduces boilerplate compared to the older Flux pattern](https://redux.js.org/usage/reducing-boilerplate).

> **Encapsulation**: In redux structure, I could access any data (No encapsulation). but, I didn't. It depends on the developer's capabilities and I can care about encapsulation as much as I want.

1. Blame JavaScript, not Redux. In JavaScript all objects are (generally) visible for the world to see: which I consider a strength because it makes scripts customizable and hackable, whereas trying to customize a third-party Java or .NET library (where object encapsulation is the norm) is very difficult if not impossible.
2. Being able to access all data in the state store **is by-design**. In Redux (and React) your state-store [is meant to be a normalized representation](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape) of your application's data, so it makes sense for it to be entirely accessible. It doesn't make sense to arbitrarily restrict what data a component can read (it's not like you're running untrusted code).
3. Remember that state in Redux and React **is immutable** (i.e. you cannot edit the data in-place), so exposing everything doesn't introduce any risks because a misbehaving component *cannot* edit state in-place.

   - To be fair, you need to use `Object.freeze` to make the data truly immutable, which I imagine most people forget to do...
4. Encapsulation, as a property of a system's design, can be a good thing - and it can be a bad thing. Encapsulation generally *makes sense* when you need to hide internal implementation details that are orthogonal (or entirely unrelated) to the data that is being modelled, such as a `Array<T>`'s internal buffer pointers or a `Map<K,V>`'s hashtable buckets. But consider that in JavaScript those types (`Array`, `Map`, etc) are built-ins and you can use them to model your immutable state: you can't see into `Map`'s buckets or `Array`'s internal pointers, so you actually *never stopped using* encapsulated objects.

> **Cohesion**: When I used redux, My code had more cohesion. Data mutation logic is placed in the slice for every feature.

I think you misunderstand what ["cohesion" actually means in this context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)). I don't see how the fundamental design of Redux and its state-reducers relate to any concept of cohesion.

> **Boilerplate code**: I indeed have to make code as the redux way in the Redux structure. I had to write a little more code in Redux structure, but it was a little bit. Rather, more parts can be reused when using Redux. When we make a controller in the back-end, we make code in a framework-dependent way. There is almost no one who makes the controller from very low levels because of the flexible design.

I cannot fully comprehend the above paragraph: the last couple of sentences have nothing to do with the rest of the text.

That said, I appreciate that Redux and React both require a fair bit of repetitive *declarations* for reducers, actions, and action-creators, but I wouldn't describe it as "Boilerplate" code because the *information-theoretic content* of those (repetitive) declarations is still very high.

> **Performance**: I  have made views for some complex use-cases using react-redux. but, I could find meaningful performance down. I think it is also meaningless that there is a performance down due to hundreds of KB of Redux packages.

- The runtime performance of Redux is unrelated to the size of Redux libraries. You are conflating completely separate issues.
- That said, I don't know where you're getting the idea that Redux requires you to have "hundreds of KB" of JS files because my last Redux project had a single `redux.js` file sized at 25KB, which was minified to `redux.min.js` which was only **6KB** in size.

  - I assume you're referring to the `@reduxjs/toolkit` library (which has 210KB of source files, but the runtime `redux-toolkit.umd.min.js` is only **33KB**.

Now there *is* something to be said about the performance cost of the Virtual DOM features in ReactJS, but ReactJS is not Redux. You're free to manipulate the DOM however you like when you use Redux directly - so this point is moot.

There is also a discussion to be had about the performance implications of having to clone immutable state compared to mutating state in-place, however immutable data has inherent qualities which mean you can safely clone-by-reference rather than cloning-by-value. And because Redux uses a directed (ideally acyclic) object-tree graph to represent immutable state it takes advantage of the fact that references to unchanged child objects can be safely passed to constructors of new immutable state (so, for example, if you have megabytes of data evenly-distributed throughout your *normalized* state graph, and your action and reducer only changes a single deeply-nested object property, then the only about `log n` data will be reallocated and copied, instead of the entire graph.

> The articles about Redux cons I read were written 2 years ago. Using the Redux toolkit is a standard way now. Boilerplate code still is a con of Redux?

**What boilerplate** are you even talking about?

> If the performance down is a con of Redux, Could you tell me specific examples? (What kind of project has performance problems when using redux, or the cases that don't use Redux because of performance.)

Think about it this way: JavaScript is far, far from being the fastest or most efficient programming language (e.g. the V8 JS engine will consume tens of megabytes of RAM just to run a simple "Hello, World" example script) - given that, I wouldn't worry too much about general performance in JS (...at least nothing beyond ensuring that any algorithms you implement in JS run in `O(n log n)` time or better).

> What is the biggest con of using Redux today? (Except that it's hard)

I'd say the biggest disadvantage is having to put up with questions like that.

> Any other thoughts or opinions, please let me know.

People use Redux because they want to ensure the data-flow through their JS code is consistent, predictable, and straightforward to reason about compared to ad-hoc JS scripts that don't conform to any overall general architecture or programming patterns. If you don't need those benefits then you *might* just be better-off doing writing ad-hoc JS.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I am comparing the react app using Redux and the react app that does not. The articles I read were about the tradeoff between using and not using Redux. I mainly referred to [this article](https://medium.com/@chandinibaratam/why-and-when-to-use-redux-b57f7dae9269). About cohesion, For example, the Data mutation logic for **Post domain** are gathered in the `PostSlice` file so there are more opportunities to reuse it and I could easily find where is logic is placed. I think I can use the representation that cohesion increased.